# Rails - auto form submit on Devise login, undefined method `permit'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am experimenting with a Rails app - I am using Devise for user login, and I am trying to set it up so that every time a user successfully logs in, a specific entry is automatically inserted into a model called `reports`.

In my Devise session controller, I have the following actions related to a successful user login:

```
def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     Report.create(report_params({"comment" => "user logged in"})) 
end

private
    def report_params(params)
        params.permit(:comment)
    end
```

So, if that's not clear, what I mean to do is create a new entry in `reports` every time a user logs in, and that entry will always read "user logged in".

However, when I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `permit' for {"comment"=>"user logged in"}:Hash
```

I realize that this exact operation may seem a bit pointless or redundant - as I said, I'm just experimenting, but getting this right may help me to restructure a different app that I was working on (thinking about JSONs in place of this fixed entry).

If someone could explain the meaning of this error and help me figure out what I am doing wrong (or if this is the best way to accomplish such a task), that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do this just add this in your create action

```
def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    Report.create(comment: "user logged in")
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

So ass soon as the resource is authenticated there will be a new report created after every single sign_in. comment below if you need more

Answer (score 1):

The *Answer* given by *@Chirag Arya* should work for you. I will focus on explaining the error.

> undefined method `permit' for {"comment"=>"user logged in"}:Hash

The problem is the [***permit***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/permit) should be called on [***ActionController::Parameters***](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html), but you are calling it on  a ***hash***. Notice that you are overriding the normal `params` with a hash(`{"comment"=>"user logged in"}`) in `report_params` method.

```
h = {"comment"=>"user logged in"}
 => {"comment"=>"user logged in"} 

h.permit
NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for {"comment"=>"user logged in"}:Hash

a = ActionController::Parameters.new({"comment"=>"user logged in"})
=> {"comment"=>"user logged in"}

a.permit(:comment)
=> {"comment"=>"user logged in"}
```

Also, I noticed that you are *wrongly using* `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`, a *Devise helper method* which is meant to server a different purpose. [***See why this method is used***](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)